# using UITabBarController not in top level view

Tags: ios, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller

i'm building app for cars ...

app first view is cars listed in table "UITableViewController", when user select a car "cell" the app navigates to "UITabBarController", because for each car there are a lot of infos and specification that need to be displayed in separate view, so i use here "UITabBarController"

so the tab bar controller is not in the top view level....

**Question 1:** is this correct usage of the UITabBarController? i'm afraid of getting rejected from apple app review ,i read in apple docs

> "In general, use a tab bar to organize information at the app level. A
>   tab bar is well-suited for use in the main app view because it’s a
>   good way to flatten your information hierarchy and provide access to
>   several peer information categories or modes at one time."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41

**Question 2:** are there any apps in the market that don't put the tab bar controller in the top view level! plz give me links to them......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key words here are "peer information categories". That means information which is related by a common theme, in this case a specific model of cars.

So a structure that had a tab for engine data, a tab for interior spec, a tab for fuel performance and so on would be perfectly fine.  All the tabs display data that relates to the same car.  What would make less sense is if you mixed things up by including a tab that wasn't related to the selected car.

Ideally you'd want to embed the `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController` so that the navigation bar would display the context (say the car name or something similar) and a back navigation button to provide access back to the table view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's, your app will not get rejected.
2. There are should be app using the tabbarcontroller like you are going to use, but I don't know them.